# Expectation Of a Poisson RV conditioned on several r.v.'s

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

I have this problem:
Given five independent Poisson Random variable (not necessary identical): $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$,$X_4$, $X_5$,  need to find the conditional expectation: 
$\mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid X_2, X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4, X_1+X_2+X_3+X_5 \}$.

Here is what I have done:

1. Subtracting $X_2$ from the other given r.v.

   $= \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid X_1+X_3+X_4, X_1+X_3+X_5 \}$
2. define $\alpha = X_1+X_3+X_4 $, $\beta=  X_1+X_3+X_5  $

   $= \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid\alpha, \beta \} = \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid\alpha-\beta, \beta \}$ 
   ( since we can always get back $\alpha$ and $\beta$ )
3. now noticing that $X_1$ is independent of $\alpha - \beta$ , we have :

   $= \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid \beta \}$

   $= \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid X_1+X_3+X_5 \}$ 
   $= \mathbb{E} \{ X_1 \mid X_1+X_{3,5} \}$

Where I defined $X_{3,5} = X_{3}+X_{5}$, since $X_{3,5}$ is independent of $X_1$ we can use an earlier result that shows that the above is mean of Binomial distribution.
Now my questions:

1. Is what I did above (especially step 1 and 2) correct?
2. Is there a more rigorous way to write step #2
3. If it is incorrect, can we get a close form for this expectation?

Comment: I think $E(X_1\mid \alpha - \beta,\beta)=E(X_1\mid \beta)$ in Step 3 is wrong: $X_1$ and $\alpha - \beta$ are independent but not _conditionally_ independent given $\beta$. E.g. If $\beta=1$ and $\alpha - \beta=-1$ then we must have $X_1=0,X_3=0,X_5=1$ but with only $\beta=1$ it is possible to have $X_1=1,X_3=0,X_5=0$.

Comment: I think you are right, what about the first step?
 do you have any idea how solve it?

Comment: I think Step 1 is good. As to progressing past Step 2... not sure of a way other than expanding $E(X_1\mid \alpha,\beta)$ in terms of nested sums.

Comment: Thanks, Mick A
This might be naive question, but Is it possible to replace $\alpha$ , $\beta$ with $\min(\alpha,\beta)$ ?  because I think this can simplify the expectation a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that works because $X_4$ and $X_5$ are not identically distributed. Even if they were, there's still a problem in that, given $\alpha,\beta$ then for each instance of values of the $X_i$s satisfying them, we must have $X_4-X_5=\alpha-\beta$, affecting the probability of those values occurring, and we'd lose that information if we only had $min(\alpha,\beta)$.